# Get the value most common in the array, or show mixed result

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which stores answers to a quiz. The answers given can be A, B or C and there are four questions.

I'm trying to work out how many answers of each were given so I can push the user forward to the following screens:

- Mostly A's
- Mostly B's
- Mostly C's
- Mixed (e.g AABB)

I have used the following to get a count for each instance:

```
$most = array_count_values($answers[0]);
```

Which gets the result:

```
array(2) {
   ["a"]=> int(3)
   ["b"]=> int(1)
}
```

1) How can I get the value with the highest `int` number? E.g in case above it would be "A" ?

2) How can I differentiate if there is no `highest` value? E.g in the case below:

```
array(2) {
    ["a"]=> int(2)
    ["b"]=> int(2)
    }
```

In this case I need the answer "mixed".

How would you go about this? Having looked into using the `max()` function I can see it does not have the option for working out where there are two feasible options.

Comment: I have corrected the answer! check it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to retrieve the index key (a, b or c) from the highest integer value. If I'm wrong please correct me.

You can do this like so:

```
$ar= array(
   "a"=> 3,
   "b"=> 6,
    "c"=> 9

);

 $max = array_keys($ar, max($ar));
 echo $max[0];
```

$max will be an array that contains all keys with the highest value. if for example A and B have the same value and are the highest then you can access both value with `max[0]` and `max[1]`. Similar you can count how many equal "winners" you have by getting the length of the $max array (`count($max)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the highest value with the function [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php). It will sort your array by value from highest to lowest.

To check if there is a tie, you can check if array element 0 ==  array element 1.

```
$a = array(
    'A' => 1,
    'B' => 5,
    'C' => 2
);
arsort($a)

$highest = $a[0];
$tie = ($a[0] == $a[1]) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare the value using `current` and `end` method as like below

```
$most = array("a"=>3, "b"=>1); 
sort($most);
$min = current($most);
$max = end($most);

if($min == $max){
  echo "mixed";
}else{
  echo "Highest: ".max($most);
}
```